# Pass a generic delegate as Method parameter in C#

Tags: c#, parameters, methods, delegates

I have this delegate declaration:

```
public delegate IEnumerable<T> SearchInputTextStrategy<T, U>(string param);
```

Lets assume I did create here the new SearchInputTextStrategy delegate and name it MyDelegate.

this is my method declaration:

```
public void BindElements<T, TDisplayProperty,TSortProperty>
(
       IEnumerable<T> dataObjects,
       Func<T, TDisplayProperty> selectorDisplayMember,
       Func<T, TSortProperty> selectorSortMember,
       string delimiter,
       // 1.) how to declare the delegate here as parameter ??
)
{
    // pass here the delegate to a private field to save it
    // 2.) how can I do that?

}
```

How can I do 1.) and 2.) ? :-)

**UPDATE 2:**

Ok thats what I have done so far:

```
public class SearchProvider<T>
    {
        public delegate IEnumerable<T> SearchInputTextStrategy<T>(string param);    

        public SearchInputTextStrategy<T> SearchStrategy { get; set; }

        public T TypedValue
        {
            get
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(SearchStrategy, typeof(T));
            }
        }
    }
```

**UserControl:**

```
 public delegate IEnumerable<T> SearchInputTextStrategy<T>(string param);

 public void BindElements<T, TDisplayProperty,TSortProperty>
        (
            IEnumerable<T> dataObjects,
            Func<T, TDisplayProperty> selectorDisplayMember,
            Func<T, TSortProperty> selectorSortMember,
            string delimiter,
            SearchInputTextStrategy<T> searchStrategy
        )
        { 
               /// assign the searchStrategy to the SearchProvider class 
            var sp = new SearchProvider<T>();
                sp.SearchStrategy = searchStrategy  // DOES NOT WORK !!!     
        }
```

Please read also my comments in the Code. What I want to achieve is pass the delegate to the searchProvider to save it somewhere... The code I write here I understand up to 50 % so please bear with me Generics are new to me  although I use generic List for a long time ;P

**UPDATE 2:**

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public delegate IEnumerable SearchInputTextStrategy(string param);

```
    private SearchInputTextStrategy<ICustomer> _strategy;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

        IEnumerable<ICustomer> customers = DataService.GetCustomers();                  

        _strategy = new SearchInputTextStrategy<ICustomer>(SearchCustomers);           


        ElementUserControl.BindElements(customers, c => c.FirstName, c => c.SortId, ";", _strategy);

namespace ElementTextBoxV2
{      

        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public delegate IEnumerable<ICustomer> SearchInputTextStrategy<ICustomer>(string param);

            private SearchInputTextStrategy<ICustomer> _strategy;

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();            

                IEnumerable<ICustomer> customers = DataService.GetCustomers();                  

                _strategy = new SearchInputTextStrategy<ICustomer>(SearchCustomers);           


                ElementUserControl.BindElements(customers, c => c.FirstName, c => c.SortId, ";", _strategy);

                IEnumerable<ICustomer> selectedElements =  ElementUserControl.SelectedElements<ICustomer>();
            }

            // Just a Test-Methode to assure the delegate works
            public IEnumerable<ICustomer> SearchCustomers(string param)
            {
                IEnumerable<ICustomer> foundCustomers = new List<ICustomer>();
                return foundCustomers;
            }         
        }
    }
```

The scenario is, that the user has put the TextBoxUserControl in a MainWindow and he has to pass a  delegate pointing to a searchMethod. I have implemented this with the SearchCustomers_Method. The problem is that C# can not resolve that:

```
    Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'ElementTextBoxV2.ElementsView.BindElements<ElementTextBoxV2.ICustomer,string,int>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ElementTextBoxV2.ICustomer>, System.Func<ElementTextBoxV2.ICustomer,string>, System.Func<ElementTextBoxV2.ICustomer,int>, string, ElementTextBoxV2.Provider.SearchInputTextStrategy<ElementTextBoxV2.ICustomer>)' has some invalid arguments

Error   2   Argument 5: cannot convert from 'ElementTextBoxV2.MainWindow.SearchInputTextStrategy<ElementTextBoxV2.ICustomer>' to 'ElementTextBoxV2.Provider.SearchInputTextStrategy<ElementTextBoxV2.ICustomer>'
```

Do you see the problem? In any case the User must pass a delegate with the same definition the BindElements Method has!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's odd that your `SearchInputTextStrategy` has two type parameters but only actually uses one... but you just need to specify the type arguments in the parameter type. For example:

```
public void BindElements<T, TDisplayProperty,TSortProperty>
(
    IEnumerable<T> dataObjects,
    Func<T, TDisplayProperty> selectorDisplayMember,
    Func<T, TSortProperty> selectorSortMember,
    string delimiter,
    SearchInputTextStrategy<T, TDisplayProperty> searchStrategy
)
```

I've only *guessed* at what the type arguments should be - you haven't really said what you want the parameter to represent.

You won't be able to easily have a field of the right type in your class, because the class itself doesn't know the type parameters involved. It's possible that you should really be making your class generic, or make *another* class which is able to handle the delegates appropriately. Without any more information, it's very hard to know which.

Comment: I bet, that the second type parameter for delegate should be `TSortProperty`. But that's just a guess like yours

Comment: @Jon and alpha-mouse: oh no the second type parameter has nothing to do with the TSortProperty or TDisplayProperty its just a string which is passed to the delegate which serves as search pattern on the database.

Comment: @Jon alone...: quote:"It's odd that your SearchInputTextStrategy has two type parameters but only actually uses one... " TWO ? well its the parameter string and the return value T, NOT?

Comment: @Lisa: No, *type* parameters: `T` and `U`. You use `T` (for the return type) but never `U`. Why have you included `U` in the delegate declaration at all?

Comment: @Jon forget about the U sorry its just => ublic delegate IEnumerable<T> SearchInputTextStrategy<T>(string param); OK Jon lets say I create a public class SearchProvider<T> the I could even use a generic property, so would it then be possible to save the delegate in a field? The PROBLEM right now is that the type SearchInputTextStrategy is KNOWN nowhere...

Comment: @Lisa: Okay, that makes it easier. You say that "the type SearchInputTextStrategy is KNOWN nowhere" - but it's a public delegate. I don't see what the problem is. You can store it in a field of type `SearchInputTextStrategy<T>` within a `SearchProvider<T>`.

Comment: I have updated my initial question with a code sample, please check that Jon, thank you and good night :)

Comment: @Lisa: "DOES NOT WORK" isn't exactly a great description of what's wrong, as you haven't specified anything about `SearchProvider<T>`. If you make `SearchProvider<T>.SearchStrategy` a property of type `SearchInputTextStrategy<T>` that should work fine.

Comment: ah I could not resist ;-) yes sorry your are right, thats the propert error message of my new updated code:  Error 11 Cannot implicitly convert type 'UserControlElementsView.SearchInputTextStrategy<T>' to 'Provider.SearchProvider<T>.SearchInputTextStrategy<T>' What do I wrong?

Comment: @Lisa: It sounds like you've declared the delegate in two different places. Don't do that. Declare it once, probably at the namespace level (i.e. not inside any other type).

Comment: yes I have declared the delegate i 2 places. Ah I can declare at namespace level cool never have seen that before, have to check how doing that ;-) cu latesssss....

Comment: @Jon ok I put the delegate above the class declaration in the namespace area now works! and I remove the 2nd declaration. I updated the init post again with a final question :)

Comment: ok ok I will ask the last problem in an extra question so you get points again ;P hey and I surely buy your new book out now!

Comment: ok I got the last problem working too by putting the concrete delegate in the namespace too of the MainWindow:  public delegate IEnumerable<ICustomer> SearchInputTextStrategy<ICustomer>(string param); :) and now I ordered your book :P

Comment: @Lisa: Cool - hope you like it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
private SearchInputTextStrategy<T, string> _searchStrategy;

public void BindElements<T, TDisplayProperty,TSortProperty>
(
       IEnumerable<T> dataObjects,
       Func<T, TDisplayProperty> selectorDisplayMember,
       Func<T, TSortProperty> selectorSortMember,
       string delimiter,
       SearchInputTextStrategy<T, string> searchStrategy
)
{
    _searchStrategy = searchStrategy;
}
```

Comment: Hey David, why did you use TDisplayProperty and not string? AND that will not work => SearchInputTextStrategy as field because its not known as type